# How to replace multiple <blockquote> in textarea JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is just an example with jQuery:

```js
$('.quoteMsg').click(function() {
  var txt = $(this).closest('.replyBox').find('.replyMsg').html();
  txt = txt.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' ');
  txt = txt.replace(/<\/blockquote>/gi, '\n');
  txt = txt.replace(/<blockquote>/gi, '');

  console.log(txt);
  $("textarea[name='quote']").val($.trim('[quote]' + txt + '[/quote]'));
});
```

```css
blockquote {
  background-color: silver;
}

.replyMsg {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.quoteMsg {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="comment" name="quote" placeholder="quote" style="width:80%;height:200px;"></textarea>
<section class="replyBox" style="width: 100%;"><br/>
  <a href="#napisz" class="quoteMsg"> [ click for quote ] </a>
  <div class="replyMsg">
    <blockquoteid ="a1" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment&#128526; </blockquote>
    <blockquote  id ="a2 contenteditable="true" contenteditable="true">>this is a quote for comment text1</blockquote>
    <blockquote  id ="a3" contenteditable="true" contenteditable="true">>this is a quote for comment text2</blockquote>
    <blockquote  id ="a4" contenteditable="true" contenteditable="true">>this is a quote for comment text3</blockquote>
  </div>
</section>
```

Convert `blockquote` to `textarea`. How to do it be free of sources I want to change the  tag to `<br />` or a new line in the `textarea`. Alternatively, change to some other character.

Comment: Please differentiate between jQuery and JavaScript. Your code indicates the usage of jQuery, not vanilla JavaScript. If you're using jQuery, then always tag your question with jQuery (using JS additionally as a tag is acceptable) and name it jQuery within your description.

Comment: i saw this is just example mr tacoshy thanks

Comment: i edit again please let friend see

Comment: @wshyarxoshnaw Hi, I've updated your question and your code snippet. Please, remember that the `contenteditable="true"` should appear once per tag.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez while your edit was done with good attempts, **never** edit typos or mistakes in the code yourself but point them out within the comments. Such edits have to be done by the OP himself as such typos might be crucial to the issue itself!

Comment: You're right. Thanks, @tacoshy, and well done with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. You get all blockquotes with JS with the usage of `querySelectorAll` which will return a node list
2. you iterate through the node list with `forEach`
3. you copy the text from the blockquote and add it to a pre-declared global variable using `+=` and `element.textContent`
4. You add a new line by using `\n` at the end of the string from step 3
5. you remove the blockquote with the `remove()` function
6. You create a new textarea by using the `createElement()` function
7. You set a value to the textarea with the text variable from step 3
8. You append the textarea to your document

```js
const BLOCKQUOTES = document.querySelectorAll('blockquote');
let text = '';

BLOCKQUOTES.forEach(blockquote => {
  text += `${blockquote.textContent}. \n`;
  blockquote.remove();
})

let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.value = text;
document.body.appendChild(textarea);
```

```css
/* just as proof of concept that the element really are textareas */
textarea {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<blockquote id="a1" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment&#128526;</blockquote>
<blockquote id="a2" contenteditable="true" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text1</blockquote>
<blockquote id="a3" contenteditable="true" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text2</blockquote>
<blockquote id="a4" contenteditable="true" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text3</blockquote>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the results can be displayed in one text area

Comment: edited the code so that all quotes are in the same textarea separated by linebreaks

Comment: mr tacoshy im verry sorry for that im work dynamic <blockquote>  can add using submit button. that's not find my <blockquote>

Comment: if you have a new question, then add a new question and add all relevant details and clarity at once not as a progress. Also, pay extra attention to basic grammar.

Comment: ok thnks i well take new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77479054/how-to-replace-multiple-blockquote-in-textarea-using-submit-button-and-find                                                                                     I have updated my question. Thank you for your answer