# How to replace multiple <blockquote> in textarea using submit button, and find <blockquote >id ,JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here it shows all the IDs. I want it to show only the ID "sert" and not the ID "ranya"
Do not show it directly, but through submit button.
Find the number of blockquote IDs through a loop
​

```js
const BLOCKQUOTES = document.querySelectorAll('blockquote');
let text = '';

BLOCKQUOTES.forEach(blockquote => {
  text += `${blockquote.textContent}. \n`;
  blockquote.remove();
})

let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.value = text;
document.body.appendChild(textarea);
```

```css
/* just as proof of concept that the element really are textareas */
textarea {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<button id="submitBtn">Show Quotes</button>
<blockquote id="sert-1" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment&#128526;</blockquote>
<blockquote id="sert-2" contenteditable="true" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text1</blockquote>
<blockquote id="ranya-1" contenteditable="true" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text2</blockquote>
<blockquote id="ranya-2" contenteditable="true" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text3</blockquote>
```