# How to replace multiple <blockquote> in textarea using submit button, and find <blockquote >.JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here it shows all the IDs. I want it to show only the ID "sert" and not the ID "ranya" Do not show it directly, but through submit button. Find the number of blockquote IDs through a loop​

To modify the provided script to only show blockquotes with the ID "sert" and not "ranya", and to include a submit button to trigger this action, Thats how i would do it, hope it helps you.:

-Add a submit button to your HTML.
-Modify the JavaScript to include an event listener for the button click.
-Update the loop to only select and display blockquotes with the ID "sert".

First, add the submit button to your HTML:

```
<button id="submitBtn">Show Quotes</button>

<blockquote id="sert-1" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment&#128526;</blockquote>
<blockquote id="sert-2" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text1</blockquote>
<blockquote id="ranya-1" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text2</blockquote>
<blockquote id="ranya-2" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text3</blockquote>


Then, modify your JavaScript as follows:

document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const BLOCKQUOTES = document.querySelectorAll('blockquote');
    let text = '';

    BLOCKQUOTES.forEach(blockquote => {
        if (blockquote.id.startsWith("sert")) {
            text += `${blockquote.textContent}.`enter code here` \n`;
        }
    });

    let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textarea.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
});

/* Styling for the textarea */
textarea {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 60vh;
}
```

Comment: Dont repost your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77479054/how-to-replace-multiple-blockquote-in-textarea-using-submit-button-and-find

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the unused blockquotes invisible by using `blockquote.style.display = "none"` inside the loop.

Alternatively if you think you might want the function to run multiple times you can delete the elements altogether by using `blockquote.remove()` inside the loop

Comment: would appreciate you marking my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fix the way you specify `text`:

```js
document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const BLOCKQUOTES = document.querySelectorAll('blockquote');
    let text = '';

    BLOCKQUOTES.forEach(blockquote => {
        if (blockquote.id.startsWith("sert")) {
            text += `${blockquote.textContent}.enter code here \n`;
        }
    });
    
    let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textarea.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<button id="submitBtn">Show Quotes</button>
<blockquote id="sert-1" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment&#128526;</blockquote>
<blockquote id="sert-2" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text1</blockquote>
<blockquote id="ranya-1" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text2</blockquote>
<blockquote id="ranya-2" contenteditable="true">this is a quote for comment text3</blockquote>
```

Comment: Lajos Arpad thanks very much but how if textarea have in html source with id ,javascript append to textarea

Comment: @rebazxoshnaw can you rephrase your question? I would be happy to answer, but I do not understand the question yet.